# Best approach for tracking clicks and selection based task in wix

Tags: velo

I am looking for a low code solution for a Wix website I am creating. I have the website done except for the gamified task. I am looking to present the user with 3 or 4 pictures on the page, and they must make a selection of the available pictures. The selection is either correct or incorrect based on a pre-determined decision, and the click and selection need to be stored and saved in a database. Following correctly choosing the correct or incorrect answer, the user is presented with the next question. I was wondering if anyone had any key terms to look up that are no code/low code solutions to a task like this, or examples that anyone has seen of tasks that have been made in wix/corvid like this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some code to do this. It shouldn't be too difficult to do, but there's some work involved.

Some of the APIs you'll need to use are

- `$w.Image.onClick()`
- `wix-data.insert()` (or `wix-dataset.save()`)